# Display data of the field in a Label using Function

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have around 14 pages with 6-10 questions on each which are all 
 true and false answers, Written to the DB as 1 and 0.

I have created 
 a summary page so it is printable which contains all 14 pages with all 6-10 
 questions on each then I want to display the answer by the question via a 
 Label

I am very bad at VB.net and SQL so any help on this would be 
 great

I managed to get the first one working, to display as "Yes or No" 
 but the second one doesn't work

Is anyone able to 
 formulate a function so I can just call a single line of code for each label 
 instead of having a ton of if statements?

I'm super bad at sql and vb 
 and have hardly any experience so any help will be appreciated.

This is 
 the code I currently have, Please edit as needed (if its even right?)

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class DraftPrint
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim comm_Id As String

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        comm_Id = Request.QueryString("Comm").ToString

        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=YK15-YKC0201;Initial Catalog=Testing;Integrated Security=true"
        con.Open()

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = con
        Dim str As String = "Select Indicator, Question, Answer From maca where community_ID =" + comm_Id.ToString + " order by Indicator ASC"
        Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(str, con)
        Dim dt_summary As DataTable = New DataTable
        adapter.Fill(dt_summary)
        Dim indicator As Integer = dt_summary.Rows(0)(0)
        Dim question As Integer = dt_summary.Rows(0)(1)
        Dim answer As String = dt_summary.Rows(0)(2)


            If question = 1 And answer = False Then
                DraftPrint1.Text = "No"
            Else
                DraftPrint1.Text = "Yep"
            End If

            If indicator = 1 And question = 2 And answer = False Then
                DraftPrint2.Text = "No"
            Else
                DraftPrint2.Text = "Yep"
            End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just one of the ways to solve it. You can prepare everything in the query as:

```
Select Indicator, Question, 
    CASE 
        WHEN Answer = 1 And Indicator = 1 THEN "Yes" /* Not sure what indicator is but lets pretend it must be 1 for success */
        ELSE "No" 
    END as Answer 
FROM
...
```

Now, one of the way to map it in code is to `Order By Question` (assuming question number)

```
 DraftPrint1.Text = dt.rows(1-1)("Answer").ToString()
 DraftPrint2.Text = dt.rows(2-1)("Answer").ToString()
 ......
```

As you see, this way everything comes from DB ready to populate your label, so all you have to do is to map right row to right label. To avoid confusion I use (1-1) technique. You could also do dynamic control creation based on your query resultset - this way you wouldn't need to know numbers of your controls upfront.